# Are there any examples of vector functions where the magnitude of the displacement vector is always equal to the magnitude of the velocity vector?

Tags: functions, vectors

For example, let the displacement vector be:$$r(t)=\begin{bmatrix}f(t)\\g(t)\\h(t)\\\end{bmatrix}$$and let the velocity vector be:$$v(t)=\begin{bmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\\z(t)\\\end{bmatrix}$$Are there any such vector functions where $\begin{vmatrix}r(t)\\\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}v(t)\\\end{vmatrix}$ for all $\{t:t\in R, t>0\}$?

If not, could somebody explain why such functions cannot or do not exist?

I know this might sound like a straightforward question but I have no idea and am genuinely curious.

Comment: Well $\mathbf v= \frac{d}{dt}\mathbf r$ so what about $\langle e^t, e^t,e^t \rangle$

Comment: If $\vec r(t) =\sum_{i=1}^3 \hat x_i a_i e^t$, then $\vec v=\vec r$.

Comment: What about dimensions ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for instance a circular path ,
$$r (t)=\begin{bmatrix} \cos t\\ \sin t\\0\end{bmatrix},\ \ \ \ \ t\geq0. $$